# Where can I find RegisterStartupScript content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have developed an IIS website that has worked perfectly fine when hosted with visual studio. I have then sent it off to the customer, who has hosted it on his machine locally and the functinality is fine. We then copy the same files onto their server (it is already set up with IIS and a DNS for an external URL) and most of the functionality works. One of the `<asp:ImageButton` tags, however, appears to just refresh the page without doing anything (there are 2 results that could happen when the button is clicked, and both call RegisterStartupScript() and I cannot see the results of the script on the page anywhere)

I guess after all that rambling of a backstory my question is this: When you call the following method, is this something that is visible on the page, as it should be called no matter what the response, so we can at least look for that and see if it is getting through to the method at all.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Ajax or jQuery(f.e. a dialog)?

Comment: No, just an `<asp:ImageButton` with an `OnClick` event.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see if `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` is called at all? What is the real code since this would not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source of generated page you should see your script or whatever you put in script parameter, for example :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", "CallStartup();", true);
```

should render as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
CallStartup();Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will put us back on track to finding the problem.

Comment: np, btw. best tool to find such problems is debugger, duplicate production IIS on local machine and then you can debug your application on IIS

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problems like this on occasion if the .NET Framework is not registered correctly or set to the wrong version. Check that the version of .NET set for the site on the server is the same as the one you developed for. You also may need to use aspnet_regiis to fix problems if the ASP.NET scripts are missing from your site or the .NET Framework didn't correctly register with IIS.